# How to serve the same backend but with different database for every frontend app that is connecting to it

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm looking to deploy my backend on a server and to have multiple frontend apps connected to it, but for every one to have different database, is there any way to handle this? I am using Node, express, mongoose, mongodb. The logic of the backend should be the same, but I need different db for every frontend app connected to backend.

Thanks and I hope this is appropriate to ask in this forum, otherwise please do let me know where I can find more information about this.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the domain that the client tried to access in the request's `Host` header. If every app connects to a different domain, you can use that to differentiate them. Otherwise, you could just send a query parameter containing the app name or identifier, and differentiate them through that.

Then, when you start the application, you could have something like an object with the application name or identifier as the key and a database connection as the value, and choose the database connection to interact with based on the application that made the request.

Comment: With the query param is not secured I think, but I have to think to request Header approach. Thank you

Comment: @AlexAlexa, doesn't have to be a query parameter, it could be a custom header you send from the client, such as `X-Application-ID` or something like that. Neither of these approaches is more secure than the other, because in all situations the server interprets something the client sends. Any client can send a query parameter, a custom header or a `Host` header.

Comment: I see, thank you for advices, I have to see if I can make on backend a handler, something like a list of domains that should accept requests from and map them to specific db